# java- creating a clock without using the built in clock class

Tags: java, loops, object

I am trying to create a program as practice in which the clock ticks every second. I tried to find information on this, but it was either too complicated for what I have learned, or not relevant.

I would like it to sort of work like this:

```
Clock starts at time: 12:00:00 AM
Clock has been set to time: 11:59:00 PM
TICK: 11:59:01 PM
```

This is the code that I have written so far:

```
public class Clock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleClock clock = new SimpleClock();
        System.out.println("Clock starts at time: " + clock.time());
        clock.set(11, 59, 00, false);
        System.out.println("Clock has been set to time: " + clock.time());
        for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
                clock.tick();
                System.out.println("TICK: " + clock.time());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Clock finally reads: " + clock.time());
    }

}
```

The GUI:

```
public class ClockView extends JFrame {

    /* -----------------Private Member variables --------------------- */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static int ROWS_IN_GRID = 2;
    private static int COLS_IN_GRID = 1;
    private static int BUTTON_ROWS = 1;
    private static int BUTTON_COLS = 2;
    private SimpleClock clock;
    private JLabel face;

    /**
     * Constructor. Takes a SimpleClock as an argument and builds a graphical
     * interface using that clock the model. The Tick button increments the
     * clock by 1 second, while the Reset button sets the clock back to midnight
     * (12:00:00AM). *
     * 
     * @param clock
     *            - the clock instance used to store the time for the view
     */
    public ClockView(SimpleClock clock) {
        super("SimpleClock Demo");
        this.clock = clock;
        this.face = new JLabel("<html><span style='font-size:20px'>"
                + this.clock.time() + "</span></html>");

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS_IN_GRID, COLS_IN_GRID));
        this.add(this.face);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(
                new GridLayout(BUTTON_ROWS, BUTTON_COLS));
        JButton tickButton = new JButton("Tick");
        tickButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                clock.tick();
                ClockView.this.face
                        .setText("<html><span style='font-size:20px'>"
                                + clock.time() + "</span></html>");

            }

        });
        buttonPanel.add(tickButton);

        JButton resetButton = new JButton("reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                clock.set(12, 0, 0, true);
                ClockView.this.face
                        .setText("<html><span style='font-size:20px'>"
                                + clock.time() + "</span></html>");
            }

        });
        buttonPanel.add(resetButton);

        this.add(buttonPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ClockView v = new ClockView(new SimpleClock());

    }

}
```

I am quit positive my logical error occurs in `public void tick()` of class `SimpleClock`

Essentially, it just switches from am to pm because I currently have the program switching at the end of the while loop. I know I have to move it, but I not sure how to as the clock doesn't even tick in the first place.

Comment: Where do you call tick? Can you use System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: @Bálint It ticks whenever he clicks the tick button in the GUI.

Comment: DId you debug `tick` ? The GUI isn't used ... the main use only the clock, is it useful to add this code ?

Comment: Your `tick` use a while loop that is not usefl. You won't only to add 1s, here, one tick will increment seconds until the hour is 12.

Comment: I asked my teacher, and he said that my logic is wrong in tick. Everything else is fine. @Bálint I haven't learned that stuff yet, so I am supposed to stick with just  using loops

Answer (score 0):

Your current `tick` method contains a lot of loop that will always end up with a time >= 12hours. Why ? Because you will add one seconds until the loop condition isn't meet. So until `hours >= 12` but also somethime until `minutes = 59` or `seconds = 59`

You should only add one seconds like the comment said: *Advances the clock by 1 second.* . 
And then do the specific checks.

```
public void tick(){
    seconds++;
    if(seconds => 60){
         seconds = 0;
         minutes++;
         if(....)
             ...
    }
}
```

Also, `morning` will always be switch here, but you should only do it if hours reach the limit